# When is a variety discrete?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-geometry

> What are the conditions for an affine variety to be discrete?

This has come up in a question I was viewing, but there was no explanation of when a variety is discrete.

Comment: I'd say this is equivalent to having dimension zero (and being reduced, but that should be a given for varieties).

Comment: Ah ok, so how could one go about proving that a variety of dimension zero is, in fact, discrete?

Comment: Is this an alternate account to P. Diddy? They asked the same question one question above yours.

Answer (score 0):

I claim that over an infinite field $\Bbbk$, the Zariski topology on a variety $X$ is the discrete topology if and only if $X$ is finite, i.e. of dimension zero.

It should be clear that a finite set of points with the Zariski topology is discrete. Given a discrete variety $X$, assume for contradiction that $\dim(X)>0$, then $X$ contains a closed subvariety of dimension one. Restricting to an open subset of such a subvariety, we conclude that $X$ contains a smooth affine curve $C$. By the Noether Normalization Lemma, there is a finite (hence closed) morphism $\phi:C\to\Bbbk$. Note that $\Bbbk$ with the Zariski topology is not discrete because any infinite subset of $\Bbbk$ is not closed. Take such a subset $U\subseteq\Bbbk$ and since $\phi$ is closed, conclude that $\phi^{-1}(U)$ is not closed either. This is a contradiction because if $X$ has the discrete topology, then so does $C$ and $\phi^{-1}(U)$ would have to be closed.